# function to check if number existsts in javascript

Tags: javascript

this is the variable that stores the array

```
var numbers = new array(1,5,9,7,8,5)

this is the function

function checknumbers(numbers,number)
{
    use strict;

    for(i=1;i<=numbers.length;i++)
    {
        if(number == array(i))
        {
            console.log('it exists');
        }
    }
}

checknumbers(numbers,1);
```

the error im getting is Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
ghanou.js:5:5
L’encodage de caractères du document HTML n’a pas été déclaré. Le document sera affiché avec des caractères incorrects pour certaines configurations de navigateur si le document contient des caractères en dehors de la plage US-ASCII. L’encodage de caractères de la page doit être déclaré dans le document ou dans le protocole de transfert.

Comment: `use strict;` -> `"use strict";`

Comment: Arrays are zero-based, not one-based. Accessing a member of an array is done as `numbers[i]`. Equality should be checked strictly with `===`. But that aside, you can just call `numbers.includes(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You did `array(i)`, which probably caused the error. Arrays are not functions, and you don't use `()` to get an element. You use `[]`. So you should do `array[i]` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#common_operations for more info.

Also, by the way you don't need to write your own function for this. You can just use [`numbers.includes(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the number is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of syntax errors in your code.
Here's a sample code to check if a number exists in an array

```js
let numbers = [1,5,9,7,8,5];

const checkNumbers = (numbers, num) => {
    if(numbers.includes(num)){
    console.log("true");
  }
}

checkNumbers(numbers, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return true or false

```
var numbers = new Array(1,5,9,7,8,5);
var result = numbers.some((n)=> n === 8);
console.log(result)
```